# Defining Data Model in BusinessObjects 4.0

Tags: business-objects

(I am working with BusinessObjects Information Design Tool, version  4.0)

I have two fact tables - FACT_MAN and FACT_TOTAL. They are defined as follows:

- **FACT_Man**:
- ...
- MP_Key
- PC_Key
- ...
- **FACT_TOTAL**:
- ...
- MP_Key
- PC_Key
- ...

There is also **FLAT** dimension in the database, defined as follows:

- **FLAT**
- ...
- Leaf

Both attributes **MP_Key** and **PC_Key** from both fact tables are connected to **Leaf** key (table **FLAT**) as follows:

- **MP_Key** n:1 **Leaf**
- **PC_Key** n:1 **Leaf**

The question is:

- should I model the universe so that I connect BOTH fact tables only to ONE FLAT dimension, **OR**
- should I use aliases, **OR**
- maybe solve the problem with contexts, **OR**
- my initial intention was to create only ONE universe with mentioned tables (there are additionaly 3 more FACT tables in the data warehouse). Would that be good approach, or should I maybe create MULTIPLE universes? If yes, what would be a valid reason for that? ... **OR**
- is there some other better approach?

Since I don't know which approach to take, could you please elaborate on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it would be beneficial to post a graphical representation of the data model. One thing I will say about using multiple universes: if the data in each of those universes will be combined in a same view, the person creating the reports will be responsible for merging the data in the report. Thus: additional work, sub-optimal data processing (not by the RDBMS but by the BOBJ environment), ….

Comment: @Kristof: here is the model: http://postimg.org/image/fe5ejsxux/

Comment: Please notice that I have added aliases. However, I am not sure is that the right approach. Additionally, I know for sure that the information from different fact tables will be represented in one report. One more info: pv_ZCO_pv and pv_ZCO_Copa are also fact tables. Thus the model has 5 fact tables, and few dimensional tables which are multiple times connected to fact tables.

Answer (score 0):

Contexts are  the way to go in this scenario. Absolutely the reason contexts exist.

If the one fact table is a summary of the other, you need to investigate using aggregate awareness

Comment: Does that mean (if you look at the model I sent) that VWD_pce_dim_elem_flat should not have any aliases, but it should be connected to TBF_COST_TOTAL and TBF_SCM_Man? (Please not that both TBF_COST_TOTAL and TBF_SCM_Man will be in that case 2 times with VWD_pce_dim_elem_flat connected)